# Are Sitecore settings always preferrable to ASP.NET app settings in the Web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, sitecore

Is there ever a case that the traditional ASP.NET appSettings should be preferred over a Sitecore setting (i.e. `<configuration><sitecore><settings><setting>`) when creating application-specific settings?  I can think of a couple of advantages of using Sitecore settings, for instance, being able pull those setting out into the App_Settings/Include folder, but I am not sure of any advantages of using the ASP.NET appSettings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest a third approach. I highly recommend creating a configuration file, and corresponding `IConfigurationSectionHandler`, specific to your project (or assembly). This prevents `appSettings` or `sitecore/settings` from becoming a dumping ground and prevents magic strings (i.e. the configuration key)  being littered in your code. This approach also allows developers to quickly identify where settings are for code in a specific assembly (the config file should be named similar to the assembly). Furthermore, using Slow Cheetah you are able to add configuration transformations to the file.

I dislike the use of appSettings for anything other than settings which are very specific to the web application project itself. Examples would be `aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys` as Trayek mentioned, `ClientValidationEnabled` or `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled`

In a similar vein, I dislike the use of Sitecore settings for anything other than storing settings for Sitecore modules or other customizations to the Sitecore system.

Comment: I was researching this and found that IConfigurationSectionHandler has been [deprecated since .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx) and they now recommend deriving from ConfigurationSection.

Answer (score 2):

I think the advantage to the Sitecore configuration route is as you describe. Namely, your settings can be segregated into their own .config file in App_Settings/Include. Moving settings outside of web.config is somewhat possible natively via the configSource attribute, but Sitecore allows for as many files as you need. That way each component's settings can be contained in their own file (and distributed as such).

The other advantage is being able to take advantage of Sitecore's config patching mechanism. If a your component installs a default settings file, but a certain environment needs to override a value, you can put a second file in place to override the values.

Answer (score 1):

We are also using the Sitecore settings for our configurations. Another advantage is that you have a nice interface to read the properties:

```
Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetBoolSetting("MySettings", false);
```

The only disadvantage I can think of is, that the files in the Inlude-folder will be rendered at runtime and the settings in the web.config not. So if you have thousands of settings you may consider to add them to the web.config.

Comment: The Sitecore configuration is built at application start, so there isn't a detriment to use them as you describe. Editing a file in app_config/include or web.config will both cause an AppPool restart.

Answer (score 1):

In our projects we tend to have the global settings, such as the URL to use to get address information, in the appSettings.config and the Sitecore specific settings in the Sitecore settings.

I think it's mainly a matter of preference, although I think there might be settings that can only be added to the `<appsettings>`, such as [aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403) (I haven't tested adding it to the Sitecore settings though).

Going on Kevin's disadvantage (at least, how I understand it), is that you can't quickly see what settings you're using - you can go to website/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx for that (although that only gives you the `<sitecore>...</sitecore>` section of the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of appSettings is that it'll run out of the box anywhere, and it's dead simple.  Everyone who knows ASP.NET knows what appSettings are.  While Sean Kearney offers some good advice, I feel it's a bit of a violation of the K.I.S.S. rule.  You already have two different options for configuration settings... why add a third?  This seems quite unnecessary, unless you are dealing with hundreds of settings.

You can quickly and easily make appSettings more manageable by putting it in its own file.